# Adjective to describe do it because you want to not because you have to

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for an adjective to describe a person who does things because they want to do them not because they have to or because it was imposed on them, for example, if you are going to coach someone you do it because you like it and not because it is part of your job.

Comment: Motivated?  You'll get closed  without an example sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're really asking for an adjective. To make this clear please give a sample sentence with a gap where the word should go. A noun describing such a person might be 'volunteer'.

Answer (score 1):

**Alacrity** (n.) meaning cheerful willingness.

> **Please do it with alacrity, not with resentment.**

**Alacritous** (adj.) as used in "an alacritous person".

> **He is such an alacritous person, always willing to help out.**

[Alacrity definition link TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/alacrity)